# Is the Facebook SDK using App Events API or Conversion API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I read that the [App Events API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/) is no longer supported in the future and I am curious whether the Facebook SDK is actually using this API under the hood or it's using `Conversion API` which is the latest one?

Can't find any info from the documentation, anyone has any idea?